# I want tot treat my data to only see event between a specific time

Tags: filter, time, powerbi, between

I have this table which contains the timestamp for different event. I added an image. Basically what  we see are different date within the year with different time[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbVpa.png). My goal utltimately, is to create a filter that would let me see the same data but only rhe ones where the timestamp is between 6am to 8am.

Most of the solution, I found helped me calculate how many I had, but I cant seem to show the actual value.

Ps* I am using a analysis services db *

Thank you

I tried to use the relative slicer function ,
I tried datesbetween function and datediff